# The Resource 'Microsoft.Web/sites/xxxxx' under resource group 'rg-idn' was not found

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I try to make a template for web app for docker. And I have the following json file:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "sites_docker_webscraper_name": {
            "defaultValue": "docker-webscraper",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "serverfarms_internet_suite_externalid": {
            "defaultValue": "/subscriptions/fea4c865-1e54-44b3-ba1d-07315468f083/resourceGroups/rg-idn-nvwa-sas_nvwa/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/crinternetsuite",
            "type": "String"
        }
    },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
            "apiVersion": "2022-03-01",
            "name": "[parameters('sites_docker_webscraper_name')]",
            "location": "West Europe",
            "tags": {
                "APM-id": "4442",
                "APM-name": "SAS_NVWA",
                "Clientname": "NVWA",
                "Clientnumber": "tbd",
                "Environment": "PRD",
                "LZ-version": "V1"
            },
            "kind": "app,linux,container",
            "properties": {
                "enabled": true,
                "hostNameSslStates": [
                    {
                        "name": "[concat(parameters('sites_docker_webscraper_name'), '.azurewebsites.net')]",
                        "sslState": "Disabled",
                        "hostType": "Standard"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "[concat(parameters('sites_docker_webscraper_name'), '.scm.azurewebsites.net')]",
                        "sslState": "Disabled",
                        "hostType": "Repository"
                    }
                ],
                "serverFarmId": "[parameters('serverfarms_internet_suite_externalid')]",
                "reserved": true,
                "isXenon": false,
                "hyperV": false,
                "vnetRouteAllEnabled": false,
                "siteConfig": {
                    "numberOfWorkers": 1,
                    "linuxFxVersion": "DOCKER|crinternetsuite.azurecr.io/crinternetsuite-webscraper:latest",
                    "acrUseManagedIdentityCreds": false,
                    "alwaysOn": false,
                    "http20Enabled": false,
                    "functionAppScaleLimit": 0,
                    "minimumElasticInstanceCount": 0
                },
                "scmSiteAlsoStopped": false,
                "clientAffinityEnabled": false,
                "clientCertEnabled": false,
                "clientCertMode": "Required",
                "hostNamesDisabled": false,
                "customDomainVerificationId": "A27256499C08A212DC5FD8B257022027F1FF0274BE78B8AADC345DF2C6F01FCE",
                "containerSize": 0,
                "dailyMemoryTimeQuota": 0,
                "httpsOnly": true,
                "redundancyMode": "None",
                "storageAccountRequired": false,
                "keyVaultReferenceIdentity": "SystemAssigned"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/basicPublishingCredentialsPolicies",
            "apiVersion": "2022-03-01",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('sites_docker_webscraper_name'), '/ftp')]",
            "location": "West Europe",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('sites_docker_webscraper_name'))]"
            ],
            "tags": {
                "APM-id": "4442",
                "APM-name": "SAS_NVWA",
                "Clientname": "NVWA",
                "Clientnumber": "tbd",
                "Environment": "PRD",
                "LZ-version": "V1"
            },
            "properties": {
                "allow": true
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/basicPublishingCredentialsPolicies",
            "apiVersion": "2022-03-01",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('sites_docker_webscraper_name'), '/scm')]",
            "location": "West Europe",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('sites_docker_webscraper_name'))]"
            ],
            "tags": {
                "APM-id": "4442",
                "APM-name": "SAS_NVWA",
                "Clientname": "NVWA",
                "Clientnumber": "tbd",
                "Environment": "PRD",
                "LZ-version": "V1"
            },
            "properties": {
                "allow": true
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/config",
            "apiVersion": "2022-03-01",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('sites_docker_webscraper_name'), '/web')]",
            "location": "West Europe",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('sites_docker_webscraper_name'))]"
            ],
            "tags": {
                "APM-id": "4442",
                "APM-name": "SAS_NVWA",
                "Clientname": "NVWA",
                "Clientnumber": "tbd",
                "Environment": "PRD",
                "LZ-version": "V1"
            },
            "properties": {
                "numberOfWorkers": 1,
                "defaultDocuments": [
                    "Default.htm",
                    "Default.html",
                    "Default.asp",
                    "index.htm",
                    "index.html",
                    "iisstart.htm",
                    "default.aspx",
                    "index.php",
                    "hostingstart.html"
                ],
                "netFrameworkVersion": "v4.0",
                "linuxFxVersion": "DOCKER|crinternetsuite.azurecr.io/crinternetsuite-webscraper:latest",
                "requestTracingEnabled": false,
                "remoteDebuggingEnabled": false,
                "remoteDebuggingVersion": "VS2019",
                "httpLoggingEnabled": false,
                "acrUseManagedIdentityCreds": false,
                "logsDirectorySizeLimit": 35,
                "detailedErrorLoggingEnabled": false,
                "publishingUsername": "$docker-webscraper",
                "scmType": "None",
                "use32BitWorkerProcess": true,
                "webSocketsEnabled": false,
                "alwaysOn": false,
                "managedPipelineMode": "Integrated",
                "virtualApplications": [
                    {
                        "virtualPath": "/",
                        "physicalPath": "site\\wwwroot",
                        "preloadEnabled": false
                    }
                ],
                "loadBalancing": "LeastRequests",
                "experiments": {
                    "rampUpRules": []
                },
                "autoHealEnabled": false,
                "vnetRouteAllEnabled": false,
                "vnetPrivatePortsCount": 0,
                "localMySqlEnabled": false,
                "ipSecurityRestrictions": [
                    {
                        "ipAddress": "Any",
                        "action": "Allow",
                        "priority": 1,
                        "name": "Allow all",
                        "description": "Allow all access"
                    }
                ],
                "scmIpSecurityRestrictions": [
                    {
                        "ipAddress": "Any",
                        "action": "Allow",
                        "priority": 1,
                        "name": "Allow all",
                        "description": "Allow all access"
                    }
                ],
                "scmIpSecurityRestrictionsUseMain": false,
                "http20Enabled": false,
                "minTlsVersion": "1.2",
                "scmMinTlsVersion": "1.2",
                "ftpsState": "AllAllowed",
                "preWarmedInstanceCount": 0,
                "functionAppScaleLimit": 0,
                "functionsRuntimeScaleMonitoringEnabled": false,
                "minimumElasticInstanceCount": 0,
                "azureStorageAccounts": {
                    "str-webcrawler": {
                        "type": "AzureFiles",
                        "accountName": "strdevinternetsuite",
                        "shareName": "fsndevinternetsuite",
                        "mountPath": "/var/www/html"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/hostNameBindings",
            "apiVersion": "2022-03-01",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('sites_docker_webscraper_name'), '/', parameters('sites_docker_webscraper_name'), '.azurewebsites.net')]",
            "location": "West Europe",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('sites_docker_webscraper_name'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "siteName": "docker-webscraper",
                "hostNameType": "Verified"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/snapshots",
            "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('sites_docker_webscraper_name'), '/2022-07-03T17_07_28_3927091')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('sites_docker_webscraper_name'))]"
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/snapshots",
            "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('sites_docker_webscraper_name'), '/2022-07-04T02_07_28_9981063')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('sites_docker_webscraper_name'))]"
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/snapshots",
            "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('sites_docker_webscraper_name'), '/2022-07-04T17_07_30_0446802')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('sites_docker_webscraper_name'))]"
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/snapshots",
            "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('sites_docker_webscraper_name'), '/2022-07-05T02_07_30_6143578')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('sites_docker_webscraper_name'))]"
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/snapshots",
            "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('sites_docker_webscraper_name'), '/2022-07-05T17_07_31_6180553')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('sites_docker_webscraper_name'))]"
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/snapshots",
            "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('sites_docker_webscraper_name'), '/2022-07-06T02_07_32_2190070')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('sites_docker_webscraper_name'))]"
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/snapshots",
            "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('sites_docker_webscraper_name'), '/2022-07-06T17_07_33_2391266')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('sites_docker_webscraper_name'))]"
            ]
        },
        
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/snapshots",
            "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('sites_docker_webscraper_name'), '/2022-08-02T03_08_19_1696825')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('sites_docker_webscraper_name'))]"
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/snapshots",
            "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('sites_docker_webscraper_name'), '/2022-08-02T04_08_19_1666344')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('sites_docker_webscraper_name'))]"
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/snapshots",
            "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('sites_docker_webscraper_name'), '/2022-08-02T05_08_19_2535918')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('sites_docker_webscraper_name'))]"
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/snapshots",
            "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('sites_docker_webscraper_name'), '/2022-08-02T06_08_19_3227599')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('sites_docker_webscraper_name'))]"
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/snapshots",
            "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('sites_docker_webscraper_name'), '/2022-08-02T07_08_19_3781004')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('sites_docker_webscraper_name'))]"
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/snapshots",
            "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('sites_docker_webscraper_name'), '/2022-08-02T08_08_19_4345008')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('sites_docker_webscraper_name'))]"
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/snapshots",
            "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('sites_docker_webscraper_name'), '/2022-08-02T09_08_19_5418008')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('sites_docker_webscraper_name'))]"
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/snapshots",
            "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('sites_docker_webscraper_name'), '/2022-08-02T10_08_19_5823928')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('sites_docker_webscraper_name'))]"
            ]
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/snapshots",
            "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('sites_docker_webscraper_name'), '/2022-08-02T11_08_19_6589523')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('sites_docker_webscraper_name'))]"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

But if I look in the log files. I see this error:

```
{
    "status": "Failed",
    "error": {
        "code": "ResourceNotFound",
        "message": "The Resource 'Microsoft.Web/sites/internetsuite' under resource group 'rg-idn-nvwa-sas_nvwa' was not found. For more details please go to https://aka.ms/ARMResourceNotFoundFix"
    }
}
```

But I don't have a value internetsuite in the template. So where is this value comming from?

Thank you

And this is the pipeline(ARM template):

```
# Docker
# Build and push an image to Azure Container Registry
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/docker

trigger:
- master

resources:
- repo: self

variables:
  # Container registry service connection established during pipeline creation
  dockerRegistryServiceConnection: 'production_internetsuite_connection'
  imageRepository: 'internetsuite-webscraper'
  containerRegistry: 'crinternetsuite.azurecr.io'
  dockerfilePath: '**/Dockerfile'
  tag: '$(Build.BuildId)'


  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build and push stage
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build and push an image to container registry
      inputs:
        command: buildAndPush
        repository: $(imageRepository)
        dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)
        containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
        tags: |
          $(tag)

    - task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
      inputs:
        deploymentScope: 'Subscription'
        subscriptionId: 'fea4c865-1e54-44b3-ba1d-07315468f083'
        azureResourceManagerConnection: 'spn-azure-contributor-002'
        location: 'West Europe'
        templateLocation: 'Linked artifact'
        csmFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/pipelines/templates/app-service/template.json'
        csmParametersFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/pipelines/templates/app-service/parameters.json'
        deploymentMode: 'Incremental'
```

And this is my parameters.json file:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "sites_docker_webscraper_name": {
            "value": "internetsuite"
        },
        "serverfarms_internet_suite_externalid": {
            "value": "internetsuite"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it is coming from the second parameter.

The values are not an exact match for the error message, but the error message is more similar to the template in the question you posted yesterday.

Comment: I get this error: ##[error]The aggregated deployment error is too large. Please list deployment operations to get the deployment details. Please see https://aka.ms/DeployOperations for usage details.

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the parameter 'sites_docker_webscraper_name' in whatever is calling the arm template? if that value is 'internetsuite' that is where it is coming from.

Comment: Hi, What exactly do you mean?